# URL rewriting rules is working weird in web.config/not rewriting sub-folder files

Tags: iis, web.config-transform

I need to rewrite the URL extensions such as .php's .html's. I am facing a situation where for ex. www.mydotcom.com/folder/file.php is working fine as www.mydotcom.com/folder/file but www.mydotcom.com/folder/folder/file1.php is not working as www.mydotcom.com/folder/folder/file1

And for URL extension replace/rewrite i am using web.config due to my windows hosting and this is the code i am using for that-

```
<configuration> 
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
   <rules> 
    <rule name="RewritePHP">
      <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions> 
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
    </rule> 
   </rules>
  </rewrite> 
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Now it is saying for every directory and every file with .php's(.html's i will resolve later)still what could be the problem

Comment: How is this even related to PHP if it's `IIS` server configuration?

Comment: Sorry, taken care off